# Put a divider/separator between two side-by-side tables

Tags: html, css

I have two side-by-side HTML tables, and they are enclosed in a `div`. They may have different number of rows and they are dynamically updated.

At the moment, there is no border on these tables (each with 3 columns), so visually they might appear like a single table. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qxRVF/1/

I want to put a divider/separator (basically a single vertical line) between them, and I want the length of the divider to be the same as that of the enclosing div, which is fixed.

How can I do this using HTML and CSS for modern browsers only? Enabling the borders on those tables is not a solution because they have variable lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a pseudo-element on the outer div: http://jsfiddle.net/qxRVF/4/

```
.table-info:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:50%; width:0; 
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap both tables in separate divs. Then set border-right propery of left div and set border-left property of right div.